# Сайт на PHP. Проблема с загрузкой с гита

Tags: php, html, sql

https://github.com/victor-zinchenko/shop.php-start.com
обучаюсь PHP. Смотрел курс по интернет магазину. Вроде всё понятно. Скачал исходники разобрать. Не могу запустить, что только не делал. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема.[image: ShopController on line 75]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код лучше прикрепить, потому что никто не будет лазить по вашему проекту на гитхабе

Comment: Если "вроде все понятно", то почему же не видите ошибку? Условие file_exists(...) срабатывает? Если да - то, что у вас в $controllerClassName ?

Comment: Проблема в том что такого класса в проекте нет.